# sed expression to extract group of the first match

Tags: sed

I have the following text:

```
somegarbageSTARTfirstgroupENDsomeendgarbage
someohtergarbageSTARTsecondgroupENDsomeotherendgarbage
...
```

I would like to extract `firstgroup` using sed.

I tried `sed -nr 's/.*START(.*)END.*/\1/p'`, but it doesn't work, it extracts all matches not only the first one.

Comment: Append `| head -n 1` or with GNU grep: `grep -Po -m 1 '(?<=START).*(?=END)'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sed -nr '/.*START(.*)END.*/{s/.*START(.*)END.*/\1/p;q}'
# or (probably faster)
sed -nr 's/.*START(.*)END.*/\1/p; t quit; b end; : quit; q; : end;'
```

Comment: ... or with GNU sed's `T` (branch on **non**-match), `sed -nr 's/.*START(.*)END.*/\1/p;T;q'`

Comment: There's no need to repeat the regex: `sed -nr '/.*START(.*)END.*/{s//\1/p;q;}' `

Answer (score 4):

With GNU [grep](/questions/tagged/grep), assuming there's at most one `START...END` per line:

```
grep -oPm1 'START\K.*?(?=END)' file
```

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), assuming the first occurrence is on the first line and that there's no `END` before the first `START` and that there's no `START` in the value to be returned:

```
awk -F'START|END' '{print $2;exit}' file
```

or

```
awk -F'START|END' '$0 ~ FS {print $2;exit}' file
```

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

```
perl -lne 'do{ print $1; last } if /START(.*?)END/' file
```

### Output

```
firstgroup
```

Comment: Both `awk|perl` will exit prematurely incase a noninteresting line appears first.

Comment: `perl -lne 'print($1),last if /START(.*?)END/' `

Comment: `awk -F'START|END' '$0 ~ FS{print $2;exit}' `  Assuming the START/END come in pairs only.

Comment: `grep -oPm1 'START\K.*?(?=END)'` to scrimp on backtracking in the best case or catch an unintended END in the worst case.

Comment: PS: Hope  you don't mind my comments. Coz I've observed folks get testy when given some comments.

Comment: Comments are welcome, thanks